# insufficient space

Tags: applications, google-play-store

i have qmobile a700 whenever i download new thing an error occurred insufficient space and i have all the data to sd card but still i get the same error if anyone know how to fix this then plz help me out I have tried many other ways but still the problem persist and the app-lib method that one was out of my understanding   .. i'll be waiting for your positive response thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted, you can download the Link2SD application from Google Play. It can link all the applications to SD card leaving your phone memory with a lot of space.